every subset of a finite set is finite?
I am currently studying set theory, more specifically, finite sets. I have done this demonstration, is everything correct or is there something that needs to be fine-tuned? Thanks for the answers.
To do this, I will use a lemma and a corollary that I have already demonstrated previously.

Lemma 1. Let $f: X\longrightarrow Y$ be a bijection and $a\in X$,$b\in Y$. Then there exists a bijection $g: X \longrightarrow Y$ such that $g(a)=b$.


Corollary 1. If $f: X\longrightarrow Y$ is a bijection and $a\in X$, $b=f(a)\in Y$, then $f|_{X-\{a\}}: {X-\{a\}}\longrightarrow Y-\{b\}$ is a bijection.

Let $X$ be finite. Given $a\in X$, then $X-\{a\}$ is finite. Indeed, since $X$ is finite then there exists a bijection $f: I_n \longrightarrow X$, so by the lemma 1 there exists a bijection $\varphi: I_n \longrightarrow X$ such that $\varphi(n)=a$ and by the corollary 1, $\varphi |_{I_{n-1}}: I_{n-1} \longrightarrow X-\{a\}$ is a bijection, that is, $X-\{a\}$ is finite, also by definition this tells us that $card(X-\{a\})=n-1$.
Let us define the following set $$F=\{m\in \mathbb{N}\mid if\hspace{0.15cm} the\hspace{0.15cm} card(A)=m, \hspace{0.05cm} then\hspace{0.15cm} B \subset A\hspace{0.15cm} is \hspace{0.15cm}finite\}$$
$1\in F$. Because if $card(X)=1$, then there exists a bijection $f: I_1 \longrightarrow X$, then $\{f(1)\}=f(\{1\})=X$, so the subsets of $X$ would be $\emptyset$ and $X$, which are finite. Now suppose that $n\in F$ and show that $n+1\in F$. If $card(X)=n+1$, then there exists a bijection $f: I_{n+1} \longrightarrow X$, so consider an element $a\in X$, then by the lemma 1 there will exist a bijection $\varphi: I_{n+1} \longrightarrow X$ such that $\varphi(n+1)=a$, and using the corollary 1 we will have that $\varphi|_{I_n}: I_n \longrightarrow X-\{a\}$ is a bijection, that is, $card(X-\{a\})=n$, so of course, $Y\subset X-\{a\}$ is finite. Furthermore, we already proved that $X-\{a\}$ is finite, therefore any subset of $X$ is finite. By virtue of the Principle of induction, we have that $F=\mathbb{N}$. That is, if $X$ is a finite set, then $Y\subset X$ is finite.

For Lemma 1: If $f(a)$ was already equal to $b$, then one could just let $g$ be $f$. Otherwise, one could define $g(a)$ to be $b$, $g(f^{-1}(b))$ to be $f(a)$, and $g(x)$ to be $f(x)$ for $x \notin {a, f^{-1}(b)}$.

Typesetting note: use \to instead of \longrightarrow - it's both easier to type and nicer-looking

If you are studying set theory, then why did you tag this real-analysis and not elementary-set-theory?

@ArturoMagidin, It has already been corrected, thank you very much for the observation.

@FrancMathDam I corrected it.

@ArturoMagidin, Yes. Thank you very much.
